# How to sync Excel file to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, symfony

I am working on a webpage in Symfony2 with MySQL database. On my page I need a big table where user can enter entry data, but there are columns which are calculated from the initial data provided. For instance: A1:"1" B1:"1" C1:"A1+B1". I want to store the data in database and fetch it from there to the table.I implemented this table in excel with all the logic. Would it be possible to import this excel file into MySQL, with the logic still working ?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the many libraries for reading Excel files using PHP at all?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, No.

You can not import excel "logic" into a MySQL table.

What you can do on the other hand is import all data columns into a MySQL table, and then using different SQL statements, techniques and logic you can select the data from your table, along with the additional calculated columns, for display in your webpage.

Eg,

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, (Column1 + Column2) AS Column3 
FROM TableName
```